# How to prove that in this context epimorphisms are 'surjective'

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

In article [AN ELEMENTARY THEORY OF THE CATEGORY OF SETS](http://tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/11/tr11.pdf) of [William Lawvere](http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~wlawvere/) I met a proposition left to reader
(poor me) and I hope someone can help me with it. It wouldn't surprise me
if it is not difficult and I am just struggling with a blind
spot. The author describes a category having certain properties. Let me also say that composition $A\stackrel{f}{\rightarrow}B\stackrel{g}{\rightarrow}C$
is denoted as $fg$ (so not $gf$ as most of us are used to). I will mention below what according to my view could be relevant when it comes to my question.

- All finite limits and colimits exist. There is a unique initial object
  $0$ and a unique terminal object $1$. The notation $x\in A$ is
  used for $x:1\rightarrow A$. Practicized terminology: $x$ is an *element* of $A$.
- Functor $A\times-$ has a right adjoint.
- Object $1$ is a generator (I would call it a separator). This comes to $f,g:A\rightarrow B$ are equal if $xf=xg$ for all arrows $x:1\rightarrow A$.
- If some arrow $x:1\rightarrow A$ exists and $f:A\rightarrow B$ then some $g:B\rightarrow A$ exists with $fgf=f$ (axiom of choice).
- If $A\neq0$ then some arrow $x:1\rightarrow A$ exists.

On page $18$ it is remarked that $f:A\rightarrow B$ is an epimorphism (*left*-cancellable here) iff: $$\forall y\in B\exists x\in A\left[xf=y\right]$$

It looks like: $f$ is epi iff it is 'surjective' in a special meaning. I managed to prove that the condition is sufficient (making use of
the fact that $1$ serves as separator) but am stuck on the necessity.
My question can also be formulated as:

> Let it be that there is an arrow $y:1\rightarrow B$ such that there
>   are *no* arrows $x:1\rightarrow A$ with $xf=y$. Based on this
>   construct (or prove the existence of) two *distinct* arrows $g,h:B\rightarrow C$ with $fg=fh$ (proving that $f$ is not epi).

I hope that there are persons here that are familiar with the article.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if that is illegal, but I upvoted solely for “poor me”. (Update: And now that I read the entire question, I don’t feel guilty about it.)

Comment: @k.stm Thanks for the upvote. Most probably "poor me" was very recognizable for you :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $f: A\to B$ is an epimorphism. If $A\neq 0$, then $A$ has a point by assumption, and hence the axiom of choice guarantees the existence of $g: B\to A$ such that $A\xrightarrow{f} B\xrightarrow{g} A\xrightarrow{f} B = A\xrightarrow{f} B$. Since $f$ is epi, we may cancel it from the left, hence $B\xrightarrow{g} A\xrightarrow{f} B = \text{id}_B$. In particular, any point of $B$ lifts to a point of $A$ by composition with $g$.

Suppose $A=0$. If $B=0$, then $f=\text{id}_0$ and the statement is clear. Suppose $B\neq 0$. Since $A=0$ is initial and $0\to B$ is an epimorphism, any two morphisms $\alpha,\beta: B\to C$ are equal. In particular, for some choice of point $x: 1\to B$ (which exists because $0\neq B$) we must have $B\to 1\xrightarrow{x} B=\text{id}_B$. As $1\xrightarrow{x} B\to 1=\text{id}_1$ holds, too, we conclude $B\cong 1$, hence the morphism $f$ equals the canonical morphism $0\to 1$. Then $0\to X$ is an epimorphism for *any* $X$ since we have the factorization $(0\to 1) = (0\to X\to 1)$, so all $0\neq X$ are terminal, and hence the category is just $\{0<1\}$ up to equivalence. In this case, $0\to 1$ is an epimorphism which does *not* lift all points. However, this example is after all excluded by Axiom 8 (which however comes after the Exercise).

Comment: Thank you very much! First paragraph takes away my blind spot. Second solves another problem for me. Also on page $18$ it is remarked that the category is balanced. Then on page $19$ there is the remark $\{0<1\}$ verifies all axioms except axiom $8$. The absence of parallel arrows in this category tells us that every arrow in it should be mono and epi. 'So all are iso' was my conclusion. But arrow $0\rightarrow1$ has no inverse...(???). I have great respect for Lawvere, but the order in the article could be better.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Thanks for the corrections

Comment: There should be no need to appeal to the axiom of choice for this statement. A constructive proof goes as follows: Let $f:A\to B$ be an epimorphism. Consider the characteristic function $\chi$ of the image of $f$ (i.e., in naive language, the map $B\to\Omega,\ y\mapsto\{\star|y\in\mathrm{im}(f)\}$). Then show that $f \chi$ equals the constant function $A\to\Omega,\ x\mapsto\top$. Since $f$ is an epimorphism, $\chi$ is constant with value $\top$, i.e. $\mathrm{im}(f)=B$, i.e. $f$ is surjective. Of course, one has to work a little bit to interpret this proof in the context of the book.

Comment: In particular, since the book uses classical logic, the set $\Omega$, defined as the powerset of the singleton $1$, is the set $2$.

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt: On which grounds are you reasoning? Is $f$ is an epimorphism, we have an epi-mono factorization $A\xrightarrow{f} B\xrightarrow{\text{id}_B} B$, so its image is the whole of $B$, no? I don't see the need to reason via the subobject classifier.

Comment: On base of: "$f:0\rightarrow B$ is epi" you prove that there is not more than one arrow $B\rightarrow C$ for every object $C$ and secondly that $B=1$ (assuming that there is only one terminal) right? That tells us directly that there are no objects having more than one element (contradicting axiom 8). Is this reasoning correct? In your prove I encounter $0\rightarrow1=0\rightarrow X\rightarrow1$. What makes you say that $1=0$? That is not the case in $\{0<1\}$.

Comment: @drhab: $0\to B$ being epi implies that any two arrows $B\to C$ are equal, but $B=1$ only follows if $B$ admits a point. In that case, $0\to 1$ being an epimorphism implies that all nonzero objects are isomorphic to $1$, and in particular, no object has more than one point. Hence, in the presence of Axiom 8, the only quotient of $0$ is $0$.

Comment: Yes, in my comment I forgot condition that $B$ has an element (=admits a point). It is clear now. Was I correct in my comment on $1=0$ in your answer?

Comment: @drhab: Oh, I meant $(0\to 1) = (0\to X\to 1)$ as an equality of morphisms :-)

Comment: Thanks again, and good luck with your study. Cheers.

Comment: @Hanno: Sorry, I should have been more precise. Define the image of $f$ as the set of those elements $y \in B$ such that there exists an $x \in A$ with $y = f(x)$. With this definition, if $f$ is only known to be an epimorphism (and not yet known to be surjective), it is not obvious that the image equals the whole of $B$ (but still true, by the proof). See [this MO thread](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/178778/in-the-category-of-sets-epimorphisms-are-surjective-constructive-proof) for more details.